# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) Python

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to convert Numerical values to words but when there is any Null values in the Dataset It gives the error.

**Input Data :**

```
Total_value

253897
587619.10
15786
NaN
354783.36
```

**Output**

```
value_words

Two Lakh Fifty-Three Thousand Eight Hundred And Ninety-Seven Rupees
Five Lakh Eighty-Seven Thousand Six Hundred And Nineteen Rupees And One Paise
Fifteen Thousand Seven Hundred And Eighty-Six Rupees
NaN
Three Lakh Fifty-Four Thousand Seven Hundred And Eighty-Three Rupees And Thirty-Six Paise
```

It works fine when all the rows having the values but gives error when any rows having NaN values

**Code I have been using:**

```
from num2words import num2words

def word(x):
    rupees, paise = x.split('.')
    rupees_word = num2words(rupees, lang ='en_IN') + ' Rupees'
    if int(paise) > 0:
        paise_word = ' and ' + num2words(paise, lang ='en_IN') + ' Paise'
        word =  rupees_word + paise_word
    else:
        word = rupees_word
    word = word.replace(',','').title()
    return word
    
    
df['Total_value'] = df.Total_value.astype(str).apply(lambda x: word(x))
```

But while executing the above script it gives the error when its finds any rows with NaN value. "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) "

Comment: First of all, attach a stack trace. Where the error comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `rupees, paise = x.split('.')` only works if `x` contains exactly one `'.'`. You can simply ignore NaNs:

```py
from num2words import num2words

def word(x):
    if x == "nan":
        return x
    rupees, paise = x.split('.')
    rupees_word = num2words(rupees, lang ='en_IN') + ' Rupees'
    if int(paise) > 0:
        paise_word = ' and ' + num2words(paise, lang ='en_IN') + ' Paise'
        word =  rupees_word + paise_word
    else:
        word = rupees_word
    word = word.replace(',','').title()
    return word
    
    
df['Total_value'] = df.Total_value.astype(str).apply(lambda x: word(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to apply the function only to non-NaN values.

```
df['Total_value'] = df.Total_value.apply(lambda x: word(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

This is likely faster than checking for nulls in the function, but marginally.